# XSLT: for-each extra response?

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, plist

I'm converting a `plist` to XML, and I'm confused why my `for-each` is returning two responses, whereas if I change `for-each` to a `value-of`, I get no return at all. Everything else works, I just want to get the single `Description`/`Title`/`Username` from my XSLT.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">

  <dict>

    <key>Playlists</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>All Items</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Playlist Items</key>
        <array>
          <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
          </dict>
          <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
          </dict>
          <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
          </dict>
        </array>
        <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key>
        <string>pID505050</string>
      </dict>
    </array>

    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>

      <key>0</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Album</key>
        <string>Funeral</string>
        <key>Artist</key>
        <string>The Arcade Fire</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Neighborhood #3 (Power Out)</string>
        <key>Track ID</key>
        <string>0</string>
      </dict>

      <key>1</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Album</key>
        <string>Untrue</string>
        <key>Artist</key>
        <string>Burial</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Archangel</string>
        <key>Track ID</key>
        <string>1</string>
      </dict>

    </dict>

    <key>Upload Information</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Playlist Description</key>
      <string>My description</string>
      <key>Playlist Title</key>
      <string>Mytitle</string>
      <key>Username</key>
      <string>Maven</string>
    </dict>

  </dict>

</plist>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <playlist>

      <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/dict[1]/dict">
        <xsl:element name="Artist">
          <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Artist']" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Album">
          <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Album']" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="TrackID">
          <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Track ID']" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/dict">
        <xsl:element name="Description">
          <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Playlist Description']" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Title">
          <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Playlist Title']" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Username">
          <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::*[1] = 'Username']" />
        </xsl:element>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </playlist>

  </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current XSL output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist>
  <Artist>The Arcade Fire</Artist>
  <Album>Funeral</Album>
  <TrackID>0</TrackID>
  <Artist>Burial</Artist>
  <Album>Untrue</Album>
  <TrackID>1</TrackID>
  <Description></Description>
  <Title></Title>
  <Username></Username>
  <Description>My description</Description>
  <Title>Mytitle</Title>
  <Username>Maven</Username>
</playlist>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also show the desired output?

Comment: Also, the plist XML input you showed is not well-formed, which makes it hard to guess what the real structure is and why your XPaths and patterns may not be working as you expect.

Comment: You are getting two sets of `Description`/`Title`/`Username` becuase your XPath expression `/*/*/dict` matches two `dict `elements: the one after key `Upload Information`, which is presumably the one you want, and the one after key `Tracks`, which has no children that match expressions in your `value-of` element and so the corresponding output has no content.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Unfortunately I don't have any control over the input XML (Plist), which is why I was changing it to form my own XML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming a few things since your question is not too clear:

- The example XML and XSLT are not-well formed, so I closed the root element
- You want a list of *all tracks* not just the first, followed by the playlist upload info
- I took the liberty to wrap each track in a  element in the output XML.

I then made your for-each XPath selection more explicit:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//dict[preceding-sibling::*[1]='Tracks']/dict">
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="//dict[preceding-sibling::*[1]='Upload Information']">
```

Similarly, I clean up the XPath for value-of, for example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Artist']" />
```

Note the use of local-name() to check that the first preceding-sibling node is actually called "key". Your input data is not very good XML :)

Finally, I clean up the element creation, etc. Here's the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <playlist>
        <xsl:for-each select="//dict[preceding-sibling::*[1]='Tracks']/dict">
            <Track>
                <Artist>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Artist']" />
                </Artist>
                <Album>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Album']" />
                </Album>
                <TrackID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Track ID']" />
                </TrackID>
            </Track>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="//dict[preceding-sibling::*[1]='Upload Information']">
            <Description>
                <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Playlist Description']" />
            </Description>
            <Title>
                <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Playlist Title']" />
            </Title>
            <Username>
                <xsl:value-of select="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key'] = 'Username']" />
            </Username>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </playlist>
</xsl:template>
```

And here's the resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist>
   <Track>
      <Artist>The Arcade Fire</Artist>
      <Album>Funeral</Album>
      <TrackID>0</TrackID>
   </Track>
   <Track>
      <Artist>Burial</Artist>
      <Album>Untrue</Album>
      <TrackID>1</TrackID>
   </Track>
   <Description>My description</Description>
   <Title>Mytitle</Title>
   <Username>Maven</Username>
</playlist>
```

Comment: This source XML has no namespaces, so `preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='key']` is identical to `preceding-sibling::key[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this alternative transform, which uses templates instead of `for-each` elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <playlist>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="plist/dict/dict[preceding-sibling::key = 'Tracks']/dict" mode="track"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="plist/dict/dict[preceding-sibling::key = 'Upload Information']" mode="info"/>
    </playlist>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dict" mode="track">
    <track>
      <Artist>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key = 'Artist']"/>
      </Artist>
      <Album>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key = 'Album']"/>
      </Album>
      <TrackID>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key = 'Track ID']"/>
      </TrackID>
    </track>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dict" mode="info">
    <info>
      <Description>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key = 'Playlist Description']"/>
      </Description>
      <Title>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key = 'Playlist Title']"/>
      </Title>
      <Username>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key = 'Username']"/>
      </Username>
    </info>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<playlist>
   <track>
      <Artist>The Arcade Fire</Artist>
      <Album>Funeral</Album>
      <TrackID>0</TrackID>
   </track>
   <track>
      <Artist>Burial</Artist>
      <Album>Untrue</Album>
      <TrackID>1</TrackID>
   </track>
   <info>
      <Description>My description</Description>
      <Title>Mytitle</Title>
      <Username>Maven</Username>
   </info>
</playlist>
```